# Why hibernate do Executing identity-insert immediately

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I run test I see in logs `Executing identity-insert immediately` Why hibernate run immediately insert? I expect insert during commit.

```
On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
begin
Executing identity-insert immediately

    /* insert MyJpaClass
        */ insert 
        into
            MyJpaClass
            (id, message) 
        values
            (null, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert MyJpaClass
        */ insert 
        into
            MyJpaClass
            (id, message) 
        values
            (null, ?)
Natively generated identity: 1
HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
committing
Processing flush-time cascades
Dirty checking collections
Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
Listing entities:
MyJpaClass{id=1, message=text}
Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
```

This is my test example
Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="HelloWorldPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
          value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersistTest {
    Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(PersistTest.class);

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    protected static EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown(){
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersist_success() {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        MyJpaClass o = new MyJpaClass();
        o.setMessage("text");
        em.persist(o);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        assertNotNull(o.getId());
        LOG.debug(o.getId());
    }
}
```

Entity

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyJpaClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String message;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you use GenerationType.IDENTITY, the insert is executed directly without waiting for the commit because you need to get the id. And in order to get the id, you have to execute the insert in the database.

That's why GenerationType.SEQUENCE is more efficient, the insert can be postponed and you can enable batching with this strategy.

More informations about the differents strategies : https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/

Answer (score 0):

The word `immediately` in the `Executing identity-insert immediately` means:

> Does the event context require access to the identifier **immediately**
>   after execution of the method (if not, post-insert style id
>   generators may be postponed if we are outside a transaction).

When you are in a transaction you need the identifier immediately after execution of the method. So immediately provides it for you.

When you persist the insert base on your [isolation level](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) you can have or haven't access to the data in other sessions.